# is there any easy way to convert output of the type() function in python to string?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that guesses a type of a variable represented as a string.
So if I've got a variable of some type then in order to find out what type of a variable it is I can use python's `type()` function like this `type(var)`. But how do I concisely and pythonicaly convert the output of this function into a string so that the output would be like 'int' in case of the integer, 'bool' in case of the bool etc.
The only way I see I can do this is first use `str(type(var))` and then use a regular expression to strip the part indicating the type.

So basically I could write a simple type guessing python function as follows:

```
import ast
import re


def guess_type(var):
    return re.findall('\w+',str(type(ast.literal_eval(var))))[1]
```

where var is of type `str`. But my question is "Is there a more simple way to get the same result?"

Speaking of performance:

```
In [156]: %timeit guess_type
10000000 loops, best of 3: 28.1 ns per loop.
```

Comment: Why do you convert the type to a string? What is the overall purpose here? If you want to check the type, I don't get why you need regex.

Comment: How am I supposed to check type of '[1, 2, 3]'?

Comment: It will tell you it's a list... EDIT wait, you have a string representation of a list? So use `ast.literal_eval` and get the type of that

Comment: @roganjosh That's what I did. But to get the type of that I used `type()` function but it doesn't return string. Anyway, Ignacio and FlashTek have already given me the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Ok, but I don't get how `__name__` is useful in controlling flow of a program rather than comparing actual types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> type(0).__name__
'int'
>>> type('').__name__
'str'
>>> type({}).__name__
'dict'
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 4):

What are you actually trying to do? If you just want to get the name of the class of the object you could use:

```
type(var).__name__
```

This will give you the name of the class of the object `var`.